# Git log - inconsistency in file states

Tags: git

I'm looking at parsing some git logs to trace a file through history, I want to run some tools (like cloc) at each iteration. I'm defensively checking if the file status is consistent and makes sense at each commit as it is processed. I have found a file in a repo I am processing (Jekyll) that the logs seem inconsistent for. If I run:

`git log --format=format:"%H, %at, %aE, %aN, %ce, %cN" --name-status --full-history --diff-filter=ACDMRTUXB -- test/test_generated_site.rb`

...the file is added, then modified, then deleted, then continues to be modified without any subsequent re-addition. Furthermore, if I look at the [file history in GitHub](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/commits/150ff1e5e4c0eb60deb80e58736cff2e1d6993f8/test/test_generated_site.rb), the deletion appears not to have happened). The state changes reported by git log are visible in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/candily/bba1144d9bff2e3fcb6b1313c174d3d0#file-gistfile1-txt-L179) (the log output is most-recent-first, and the link to the gist goes to the delete in question).

Even stranger, it's not like the deleting commit 99098dd8c7bd5465ac97e18f35d6fcbb0ce241a2 was not applied in master, as other changes from it remain in the history (for example, see the May 18th commit to lib/jekyll/convertible.rb).

I'm obviously missing something about how git log works, and would be grateful for advice on what this apparent inconsistency is? Ideally I'd like to get a consistent linear list of all the state changes for each file.

Comment: just a note regarding `I'd like to get a consistent linear list of all the state changes `: The tricky thing is that git history is not guaranteed to be linear, as there can be multiple parallel branches, which are then merged into each other. When you do `git log` on a non-linear history, the [ordering of the commits can be done in several ways](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_ordering). The merges and the way git handles file renames can be linked to your issue.

Comment: Daniel Mann: I added the GitHub tag because the GitHub history for the file in question looks like the what I want, so I was looking for some insight on how they might get that log output.

Comment: jakub.g: I understand that the branches run in parallel, and a file can be in multiple states in concurrent branches. I don't think that could cause the problem I'm seeing in this case though, unless I'm missing something? The file is deleted and never re-added before subsequent edits.

Comment: jakub.g's comment is almost certainly the key. You might want to view the topology of the commit DAG, e.g., add `--graph` to your `git log`. Note that `--graph` changes the sorting (`--graph` implies `--topo-order`) so it may change what you're seeing as well. Your specific version of Git matters, too, as the default log sort changed at some point (I'm not sure which specific revision of Git).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot confirm that this is the case for this specific example, but was able to reproduce the behaviour with the following steps:

```
git init . 
touch test_file
git add test_file && git commit -m "add test file"
git checkout -b a
git checkout -b b
git rm test_file && git commit -m "delete test file"
git checkout a
echo "edit" > test_file && git commit -am "edit test file"
git merge b
git checkout HEAD -- test_file 
git commit -m "complete merge"
```

This results in a log of:

```
> git log --format=format:%H --name-status --diff-filter=ACDMRTUXB

92dfa538ba46b1e6fa40a385940b16d7d30729f5
M   test_file

728a129c18bca0173c3699743408ee3b0b7a8e6c
D   test_file

11f55702b525b3ba3b3886cd34e83c4e4b7a3737
A   test_file
```

It is conceivable that this has happened. I won't accept this as the answer, and will instead accept a good reliable way to detect this scenario (or alternatively, a justification that this is impossible).